# Highcharts: Get stack of series

Tags: stack, highcharts, series

Stacked columns in highcharts have the stacked defined in the series like so (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped):

```
series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
                stack: 'male'
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
                stack: 'male'
            }]
```

But I cannot figure out how to get a reference to the name of the stack from the series.
Is there any way to get the stack from the series object? I specificially need it for the tooltip:

```
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.series.stack // is undefines
                +'</b><br/>'+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y;    
        }
    },
```

Comment: You should log `this.series` the see what's available to get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `this.series.options.stack` instead.
The `series.options` object contains the options that were set for that series while constructing the chart

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>'+ this.series.options.stack + '</b><br/>'+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y;    
    }
}
```

**[Accessing chart/series options | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/v3yCR/)**